# Dovecot chdir failed - not a directory

Tags: dovecot, imap

I have set up Postfix + Dovecot with SSL enforced, and while testing with mailutils I'm able to send e-mails to my gmail, but when I try to reply they are not received on my server.

With openssl I successfully logged in to the imap server with

```
01 LOGIN myname@example.com mypassword
```

From which I get

```
01 OK ....... Logged in
```

But then on the server I get the following in the syslog

```
Jul 21 20:51:21 localhost dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<myname@example.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=99.99.99.99, lip=98.98.98.98, mpid=XXXXX, TLS, session=<R4ND0MSTRINGY>
Jul 21 20:51:21 localhost dovecot: imap(myname@example.com)<XXXXX><R4ND0MSTRINGY>: Error: chdir(/var/mail/vhosts/example.com/myname) failed: Not a directory
```

I check that file, and it's there, but it's not a directory. It's just an empty file from what I can tell. Does anyone have any idea where my configuration might be wrong? Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: What do you have for `mail_location` ? I'm on Debian, so I have it in `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-mail.conf`  - Mine is set to `mail_location = maildir:/var/vmail/%d/%n`

Comment: Additionally, the directory, etc. should be created automagically when the first message is received for the user.  Go ahead and remove the file at `/var/mail/vhosts/example.com/myname` and re-send yourself a "welcome" message

Comment: I'm on debian 10, and I have the same mail_location as you do. I think that file I had appeared from when I ran the command `sudo mail -f /var/mail/vhosts/example.com/myname`, but after I removed it and sent another hellow oreld nothing happened. I don't need to configure anything special with DNS do I? I have a mail entry that was created by default by my DNS manager.

Comment: Actually, i have _almost_ the same as you, mine is including vhosts: `mail_location = maildir:/var/mail/vhosts/%d/%n/`, but after changing it it didn't matter.

Comment: Can you post the output of `doveconf -n` ?  Here is the output of mine, with my domain changed to example.com - https://termbin.com/jdlb

Comment: https://pastebin.com/raw/6j0TeQiU

Answer (score 1):

First you have to ensure you have configured MAILDIR type of storage for your Dovecot server. In /etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-mail.conf this is in parameter

`mail_location = maildir:/var/vmail/vhosts/%d/%n`

where **maildir** is the keyword specifying storage type.

Second, you have to create a storage directory

`/var/mail/vhosts/example.com/myname`

manually, with appropriate ownership, permissions and SELinux labels, or just send some letter to the address, like some simple greetings about "Congrats, myname@example.com, your mailbox created" and this directory will be created by dovecot for you.

MailDir type of storage requires directories to store individual messages in files per every message. It is his main difference of MailDir from older MaiBox storage type keeping all messages in one huge flat file.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I have tried with the same mail location and with appending `vhosts/ after vmail/ and neither worked. I closed all other ports than 993 and 587 though, because I want it all to be encrypted. Do the others need to be open or something for initiation or something of the like?

Comment: @simernes you need 25 open for server to server SMTP.  In your postfix  config you can require always using SSL/TLS/ESMTP.

Comment: Thanks, after opening port 25 I can now connect with Thunderbird, and the folder was created with a bunch of content including new, tmp, etc. but I am still not receiving any messages.

Comment: Your `postmaster_address` is invalid (that should show in the logs) and that has caused issues with storing mail for me in the past.  All of this should really be in your log files though, perhaps even visible with `service dovecot status`.  This howto may be of help, it is what my config is based on https://workaround.org/ispmail

Comment: "still not receiving any messages" is next issue and not related to this topic. To use dovector as delivery agent you have to specify it in /etc/postfix/main.cf with "virtual_transport = dovecot", then in /etc/postfix/master.cf configure this virtual transport as something like "dovecot   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=DRhu user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/libexec/dovecot/deliver -f ${sender} -d ${user}@${nexthop} -m INBOX".

Comment: As KonstantinYu said, although I have other issues, the original problem has been solved, and was indeed that port 25 was blocked in UFW.